# Functional React Components life cycle

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lifecycle, use-ref

Considering the code:

```
function Comp5 () {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const valRef = useRef(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
  }, [])
  valRef.current += 1
  console.log('valRef_Current', valRef.current)
  return <div>Comp5</div>
}



function App () {
  return (
    <div>
      <Comp5 />
    </div>
  )
}
```

What´s your console output?
I think that it should be:
valRef_Current 1
valRef_Current 2
valRef_Current 3
valRef_Current 4

But the real output is:
valRef_Current 1
valRef_Current 1
valRef_Current 2
valRef_Current 3

Can anyone help me understand why?

thanks in advance

Comment: What makes you think it should render 4 times, there is only a single state update, so initial render, and updated render? Either way, you are likely rendering your app in [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) and seeing other side-effects because your console log and ref mutation are in the function body versus being in an effect hook.

Comment: You are right. It was a conceptual mistake. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your real output is [React Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), a development tool for highlighting deprecated and unsafe methods. It is automatically included with new create-react-app projects, and on codesandbox, which is where I was able to replicate your behaviour. It will cause double renders in the process of doing its job, but will not be included when you create a production build. You can usually find it wrapped around the top level `<App/>` in `index.js`.

The *expected* behaviour is actually:

```
valRef_Current 1

valRef_Current 2
```

The component mounts, increments `valRef` and logs it. The `useEffect` then sets the state with a new value which causes one additional render. `valRef` is incremented again and its value is logged. You can observe the behaviour in this snippet:

```js
function Comp5 () {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const valRef = React.useRef(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
  }, []);

  valRef.current += 1
  console.log('valRef_Current', valRef.current);

  return <div>Comp5</div>
};



function App () {
  return (
    <div>
      <Comp5 />
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your component is rendering twice initially because of `<React.StrictMode>`

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
```

This will only happen on development environment. You can remove the `<React.StrictMode>` to see the actual renders. And on that case your output will be.

```
valRef_Current 1
valRef_Current 2
```

You can check this blog [post for details](https://medium.com/@andreasheissenberger/react-components-render-twice-any-way-to-fix-this-91cf23961625)